# how to search field name in table sql server2005

Tags: sql-server

any software or source code can used?

- i have many table i database 200+ table and my boss give some project and requirement 
  and not give information for table but give field name and i would like to find field name
  for query some condition but i don't know this field in where table and i to solved its

Comment: which version of SQL Server? 2000? 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use database_name

```
Sp_help table_name
```

`This stored procedure gives all the details of column, their types, any indexes, any constraints, any identity columns and some good information for that particular table`.

Second method:

```
select column_name ‘Column Name’, data_type ‘Data Type’, 

character_maximum_length ‘Maximum Length’ from 

information_schema.columns where table_name = ‘table_name’
```

You can visit [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/05/sql-server-2005-get-field-name-and-type-of-database-table/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive what you're asking, but you can query the SysColumns table to search for field names across all tables.

```
SELECT obj.Name [TableName], col.Name [ColumnName]
  FROM SysColumns      AS col
 INNER JOIN SysObjects AS obj ON col.ID    = obj.ID
                             AND obj.XType = 'U'
 WHERE col.Name LIKE '%Price%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Metadata about table structure is exposed in the [Object Catalog Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783.aspx):

```
select name from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('myTable');
```